# Exporting a large-ish list of constants to Lua state

Tags: c, lua

Using C(99), I have a game that loads a Lua table from a Lua script.

No problems in the technical aspect, all works as intended. However, the C core uses a number of constants to define item types and such. The script actually provides weapon data to be loaded, and should use the same constants names/values for clarity.
The constants are, in C, something such as #define ITEM_TYPE_EDIBLE 2 .

So, my question is: How can I easily export a long-ish (~300 defines) list of integers to Lua from C? More than one script should be using that list, and while the size in memory is not really a concern, I am mostly looking for convenience.

I've thought of these possible solutions, but not sure which one would be better on the long run:

- A) Manually create a nested table in the Lua state processing the desired script.
- B) Manually create a lua script containing the constants, and import it in every script making use of them.

So, what do you think is the most convenient way to do this? As in, convenient to update and to use in the Lua side of things, so mods can be written easily. Item loading is all to be done at startup, so it doesn't matter if it's not a super-fast approach (as in, it won't lag the action, just the boot time)

Oh, I am using Lua 5.1, but not against using 5.2 if it makes things any easier on my task. Also not against updating the list programmatically if possible.

Comment: Note: sounds like you should be using enums; not #define.

Comment: @daumimator: Why so? #defines work perfectly for what I need and IIRC all enums are at least integer size. What possible advantage could they have?

Comment: IMO, C code should rely as little on the preprocessor as possible. Not only will enums give you a bit more type safety, and you can enumerate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - A) Manually create a nested table in the Lua state processing the desired script.
> - B) Manually create a lua script containing the constants, and import it in every script making use of them.

You forgot:

- C) Manually create a Lua script containing the constants, then when I create my lua_State, import it right then. That way, every script that uses them can assume it has been imported.

Indeed, I would generally put this script either in the executable itself or in a special file loaded by the executable.

Comment: Ah so if I I just run the tile in the state the table should remain fine? I guess that works too and saves modders the worry of including/importing extras. I'll give this method a try, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a script that generates a C header with all the integer constants set as `enum`s. Another C file that would have a function that alters Lua state either by adding a table of all those constants, or adding them individually in the global scope as predefined number variables.